# Regulating AA to 5V and achieving high efficiency

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated

I'm trying to regulate a single AA battery to 5V for charging a USB device.

I know even at perfect efficiency, it won't provide much juice (1.5v * 1500 / 5v). But what is the expected efficiency for stepping up to 5v from 1.5v? Is 80pc achievable?

Are there other issues one should worry about in designing application?

Comment: I'm just curious about the calculation you are doing. I assume 1500 is the mAh rating of the battery, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Hopefully it's not too optimistic.

Comment: That's actually pessimistic. An alkaline has 2500 ~ 3000 mAh.

Comment: Having had experience with some consumer devices that use AA batteries for this purpose (Energizer made one several years ago), you're not going to have much luck with alkaline batteries: the higher a current you draw from them, the less total power you'll get (more lost as heat due to the internal resistance - you'd get ~0.75Wh at 2A, which is less than a quarter of available capacity at 0.1A). You'll have better luck with rechargeable (NiMH), but if it's for personal use I'd say just buy a pre-built Li-ion-based battery pack.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although there are several decent DC-DC Boost Converters available, I suggest that you try to use 2 "AA" cells if you have the room.

I currently use the LM2623 boost converter from TI (formerly National Semiconductor) in several products.  This is a pretty darn decent device that *will* work from a single "AA" cell.

In a nutshell, the LM2623 runs from 0.8V through 14V and has an on-board switch rated at 2.85 Amps.  The input voltage can't exceed the desired output voltage.

The TI product page is [LM2623](http://www.ti.com/product/lm2623)

I'm also using the Microchip MCP1640 boost converter.  This doesn't have as much current capability as the LM2623 but has the decided advantage of disconnecting the output load when the chip is shut down.  This was very important in a couple of my projects.

In a nutshell, the MPC1640 starts with an input voltage greater than 0.65V but will remain running down to 0.35V.  The internal switch has considerably less current rating than the LM2623 at 0.8 Amps.

Be aware that the MCP1640 is available in 4 different variants.  We use the 1640 & 1640D versions.

The Microchip product page is [MCP1640](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/devices.aspx?dDocName=en547080)

You should also have a look at the Adafruit MintyBoost project page.  This uses a different boost converter and runs from a pair of "AA" cells.  The project is useful in its own right but even if you decide to use a different boost converter, the USB interface information is invaluable.

The Adafruit MintyBoost project page is [Minty Boost](https://learn.adafruit.com/minty-boost)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! How come you'd suggest 2x AA rather than one? Is it purely because of power reasons? Based on the other answer, 600mAh * discount us actually good enough for me. Or are there more technical reasons like heat generation?

Comment: You mention wanting to charge devices via USB.  You do get more than double the amount of energy from two AA cells as compared to one.  Depending on which boost converter you use, the difference can be significant.

Comment: I wonder if I'm stacking up the MCP1640 against the LM2623 right. Like you said, the MCP1640 has a current rating of 0.8A. So that's 0.24A at 5V (0.8A*1.5V/5V), but capped at around 0.15A at 5V anyway (Fig. 2-3). The LM2623 can do about 300mA at 5V (Fig 7). So the MCP can output just half of what LM outputs.

Comment: The main project where I use the LM2623 uses a pair of prismatic NiMh cells into the LM2623 to generate a 5.75 Vdc rail that then powers a pair of beefy audio power amp chips.  I'm getting significantly more than 1 Amp @ 5.75V into those power amp chips.  Of course, I've got about 2.4 Vdc going into the LM2623, which helps considerably.

Comment: Right. I think I'll give MCP1640 a go! I have one last question: do you know why, in 5.2 of the datasheet, RBOT is 309kOhm for both examples? I can't seem to find anywhere that suggests 309kOhm is the typical value of RBOT.

Answer (score 5):

A typical boost/step up switching regulator can provide 80~90% efficiency, or better, as calculated in Watts (Power). P = V * I

Efficiency = Output Power / Input Power

A typical Alkaline AA battery has a capacity of 2500 mAh. That is not at a constant 1.5V, but ranges from 1.6V at full charge to 1.2V when dead. If we fudge the numbers, that's 1.5V * 2500 mAh = 3.75 Watt Hours. At 80% efficiency that's 3 Watts Hours. 3 WH at 5 Volts is just 600 mAh. In an ideal circuit, you will only be able to provide 600 mA for 1 hour with a typical boost circuit from a single AA battery.

Comment: I see. So even from 1.5v to 5v, 80pc can still be achieved. I thought it'd be lower since it's 200pc+ leap.

Comment: @Kar you are looking at it wrong. The voltage may be over 200%, but the current is almost 20%. **The efficiency is calculated on Power in Watts, which is P = V * I.**

Comment: Note that trying to draw a high current from an alkaline battery will result in much lower than expected total energy, due to its internal resistance; look up some [discharge curves](http://lygte-info.dk/review/batteries2012/CommonAAcomparator.php). For example, a [common Duracell cell](http://lygte-info.dk/review/batteries2012/Duracell%20Plus%20Power%20AA%20UK.html) can provide 3.1 Wh at 0.1 A draw, but only 0.75 Wh at 2 A draw. You'd get much better results with rechargeable (NiMH) cells.

Comment: Also note the turn off voltage on the converter is as low as possible (and efficiency falls as the input voltage goes lower) but it is usually easier to get the most out of a cell if you are able to run it to a lower voltage before the converter switches off (or cannot start). This means that two cells allow you to discharge them further before cut-off.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, there are many cheap boost DC/DC converters. I bought some from sparkfun and they were working perfectly, I never measured the efficiency, but I can say that they were cold, therefore no waste dissipation of energy.
You should buy the required power rated converter, don't buy bigger one as the efficiency matters in % of load.

Comment: Does sparkfun have boost converters from 1.5v to 5v?

Comment: There are plenty of then not only Sparkfun, but you didn't mention the current rating.

Comment: Right. I can only find 3.3v to 5v on sparkfun. Not sure if I haven't looked hard enough. Mind sharing some pointers?

Comment: Mine was 5VDC Vpack, there are smaller ones with regulator NCP1402. Pololu has also NCP1402, there are some reviews at DangerousPrototypes. AT Pololu site you have a graph of efficieny, also. Perhaps using 2 AA batteries gives better efficiency.